# Python pandas - can I sort 1 column dataset into rows of matching data in another dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have half written a code and got stuck at 2nd half.

I have pulled info from a text doc and I have placed the info into pandas dataset column with data like

```
Job : one
Time :17:00
Date : Tuesday
Cost:200
Job:Two
Time :18:00
Location :England
Job :Three
Time :12:00
Date :Monday
Location :England
Cost:1200
```

I have pulled all unique categories into another dataset and made them into columns

```
Job|Time|Date|Location|Cost
```

Now I want to cycle through the 1st dataset and fill out Each new job per row into the relevant columns, happy for the columns that don't have data to be blank...

```
Job|Time|Date|Location|Cost
One|17:00|Tuesday|    |200
Two|18:00|       |England|
Three|12:00|Monday|England|1200
```

This is example. I actually have 33 unique categories.

I have no idea how to start coding this part (or if it's possible). New to scripting so been happy to get this far..

I am using pandas as putting info into tables helps my brain because I am pulling info from a text doc and python likes to squash it all up but not sure if using pandas is limiting my options.

Any help /tips appreciated

Not sure if helps but my code so far

Comment: Thank you so much for the options below. I shall try them and let you know how I get on. Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split `data` column by the first occurrence of `;` into two columns, and group by the `Job` delimiter then transpose each group.

```py
df[['key', 'val']] = df['data'].str.split(':', 1, expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

m = (df['key'] == 'Job').cumsum()

df_ = df[['key', 'val']].groupby(m).apply(lambda group: group.set_index('key').T).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
print(df_)

key    Job   Time     Date  Cost Location
0      one  17:00  Tuesday   200      NaN
1      Two  18:00      NaN   NaN  England
2    Three  12:00   Monday  1200  England
```

Comment: Wow, this worked perfectly, I had 11000 lines and 34 columns and this worked perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: @Demo **If your question is solved**, say thank you by ***accepting** the solution that is **best for your needs***. The **accept check** is below the up/down arrow at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. If you have a reputation of 15 or greater, you may also vote on the quality of an answer, with the up or down arrow. **Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question**. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html?highlight=str%20split#pandas.Series.str.split), compute an index with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html?highlight=cumsum#pandas.Series.cumsum) and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html?highlight=pivot#pandas.DataFrame.pivot).

```
(df['col']
 .str.split(r'\s*\:\s*', n=1, expand=True)
 .assign(index=lambda d: d[0].eq('Job').cumsum())
 .pivot('index', 0, 1)
 # lines below are optional
 .reset_index(drop=True)
 .rename_axis(columns=None)
 .reindex(columns=['Job','Time','Date','Location','Cost'])
 )
```

Output:

```
     Job   Time     Date Location  Cost
0    one  17:00  Tuesday      NaN   200
1    Two  18:00      NaN  England   NaN
2  Three  12:00   Monday  England  1200
```

The other (optional) lines of code are just to clean up the output (axes names, index, order of columns...). I used [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html?highlight=reindex#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) to reorder the columns to prevent an error if a label is missing, but if you are sure the names are present, a simple slice would work: `[['Job','Time','Date','Location','Cost']]`

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I went with the other option only for the fact I wasn't sure if I had to name the columns or if I could just give a range in dataframe

Comment: I don't understand your concern. You don't need to name anything, just run the code and assign it to the output variable ;) If you're taking about the rename_axis/reindex/... This is not so important (mostly cosmetic), try with and without to see the difference.